# Docker embedded DNS unable to resolve host name on the same User-defined networks

Tags: docker, networking

According to this https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks

> It is recommended to use user-defined bridge networks to control which containers can communicate with each other, and also to enable automatic DNS resolution of container names to IP addresses.

I tried with the following but it didn't work.

```
# docker network create -d bridge mybridge01
# docker run -itd --network=mybridge01 --name busybox01 -h busybox01 busybox
# docker run -itd --network=mybridge01 --name busybox02 -h busybox02 busybox
# docker exec -it busybox01 ping -c 2 busybox02
  ping: bad address 'busybox02'
```

Environment:

```
Version:    17.09.0-ce
Architecture:   amd64
Kernel version: 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64
OS: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
```

Where did I go wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: my first post and a genuine question. why do i get -2?

Comment: Yes, it's just bad etiquette to mark down without giving a reason. Common guys, spell it out. I certainly don't see anything wrong with this question.

Comment: Your example works on my system (Docker 17.11.0-ce, AWS). What environment are you running it under?

Comment: Works fine on `17.09.0-ce`

Comment: @Alkaline Thanks for the support :) What do you mean by environment? It's stated in the question too. Not sure what else you need.

Comment: What's your target environment? Docker for Mac, Docker for Windows or , Virtual Box, VMWare Fusion, AWS, Azure, etc

Comment: @Alkaline Target environment is a VPS running CentOS Linux 7.

Comment: Just ran the test against another VM with the exact same architecture in Azure and the test worked! The only difference is the storage driver. Not working being the one using device mapper and the working version was using overlay.

Comment: yes, it probably something with CentOS. A couple of things to check a) what version of the docker daemon is running in CentOs. Do a `docker version`.
Also, try to ping the ip of the container instead to take the Docker daemon DNS resolver out of the equation. Find it using `docker exec busybox02 ifconfig`.

Comment: Both VMs having the same exact version:Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:41:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:49 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false`

Pinging the IP addresses between containers (both VMs) are working. Only the hostname resoluton for one of the VM is not.

Comment: sorry for the messy comments above ^^. Didn't have enough time to get the formatting right lol